# Reserved error(-3304); there is no message for this error - Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I am writing a SQL query for my Access 2010 database. When I attempt to run it, this error appears:

`Reserved error (-3304); there is no message for this error.`

What is causing this error?

My SQL:

```
 SELECT [Cams TNEP FINAL].[Date Entered]
    ,[Cam Issues].Department
    ,[Cam Issues].Equipment
    ,[Cam Issues].[Operation Issues]
    ,Sum([Cam Issues].Downtime) AS SumOfDowntime
    ,IIf([Cam Crew] = '3', 'C-Crew', IIf([Cam Crew] = '2', 'B-Crew', 'A-Crew')) AS Crew
FROM [Cams TNEP FINAL]
INNER JOIN [Cam Issues] ON [Cams TNEP FINAL].[Cam ID] = [Cam Issues].[Cam ID]
GROUP BY [Cams TNEP FINAL].[Date Entered]
    ,[Cam Issues].Department
    ,[Cam Issues].Equipment
    ,[Cam Issues].[Operation Issues]
    ,IIf([Cam Crew] = '3', 'C-Crew', IIf([Cam Crew] = '2', 'B-Crew', 'A-Crew'))
HAVING (
        (
            ([Cams TNEP FINAL].[Date Entered]) >= #8 / 1 / 2014 #
            AND ([Cams TNEP FINAL].[Date Entered]) <= #8 / 1 / 2014 #
            )
        AND (
            ([Cam Issues].Department) IN (
                '9230-R'
                ,'9230-F'
                )
            )
        AND ((IIf([Cam Crew] = '3', 'C-Crew', IIf([Cam Crew] = '2', 'B-Crew', 'A-Crew'))) LIKE IIf('ALL' = 'all', '*-Crew', 'ALL'))
        )
ORDER BY [Cam Issues].Department
    ,[Cam Issues].Equipment;
```

Comment: My guess is that its your line `AND ((IIf([Cam Crew] = '3', 'C-Crew', IIf([Cam Crew] = '2', 'B-Crew', 'A-Crew'))) LIKE IIf('ALL' = 'all', '*-Crew', 'ALL'))` Looks like you're trying to dynamically build the AND portion of the HAVING clause by linking together the results of the first IIF with a LIKE statement and the results of the second IIF. You can't build the clause like with combined IIF functions

Comment: @D.Bachen That's not true? I have 3 other queries in front of me almost the exact same as this that work.

Comment: You can try breaking it down into smaller chunks then and seeing if you get the error to be more specific.. This is a pretty complex query because of the ongoing use of the IIF.  Can you get it work without the HAVING clause? If not, you can then focus on your SELECT and GROUP BY statements.. Layer the HAVING into the mix once you know your base query is working.

Comment: @D.Bachen I actually just started working on that - I'll post the answer if I figure it out before someone else does. Other people were having this issue with checkbox-type columns. To clarify, no, the HAVING cause was not causing this issue.